# Can't install php7 or php 7.1 with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, php-7, macos-sierra, php-7.1

I was following a couple links that had this same sequence, namely [this example](https://daveismyname.blog/blog/installing-php-7-on-mac). I was unable to get it done successfully. Here is the output from terminal

```
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$ brew tap homebrew/versions
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$ brew unlink php56
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php56
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$ brew install php70
==> Installing php70 from homebrew/php
Error: You must `brew link libpng` before homebrew/php/php70 can be installed
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$ brew link php70
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php70
MacBook-Pro-4:/ SHennessy$
```

If anybody has any ideas that would be awesome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For MacOS Monterey I faced a similar issue `/usr/local/Cellar/php` while switching between different php versions

Following steps help me to fix my issue

**Step 1**

After installing php first link that particular version

```
brew link php@7.3 //Whatever you installed
```

**Step 2**

Switching to another php version use the following commands

```
brew unlink php@7.3 //Whatever is your current active version
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4 //Whatever your desired version
```

Or you can use single command

```
brew unlink php@7.3 && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```

Comment: this one works on mac m1, july 2022

Answer (score 22):

I had more or less the same issue when installing php71.

To resolve it, I had to delete `/usr/local/Cellar/php71` using `sudo rmdir -rf /usr/local/opt/php71` and then :

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php71
```

Hope it helps.

> Everything is now outdated
>
> - All was migrated to `homebrew/homebrew-core`

Comment: `Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`

Answer (score 4):

## For php 5.6 & php 7.0

### As of now the tap is empty and all of its formulae are migrated to `homebrew/core`

#### so i untapped & cleaned

`brew untap homebrew/dupes`
`brew cleanup`

#### And tapped this repo for older php versions

`brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated`

#### And resinstalled php versions

`brew reinstall php@7.1`
`brew reinstall php@5.6`

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS Catalina you need to do this fallowing commands.

1. brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated
2. brew install php@7.1 (or other versions which lower then 7.1)

You can read more about this, just visit here https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions.

Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Venture I had multiple PHP folders under '/usr/local/opt/' so I erased the old versions and then I installed the latest.

Steps I took:
which php
cd /usr/local/opt/
rm -r php@7.0
rm -r php@7.4
rm -r php@8.0

Restart machine and then a php -v